# Limit results of SQL query with one result of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here's my SQL query :

```
SELECT 
       asi.nid_lot AS nid_lot,
       asi.nid_programme AS nid_programme,
       asi.mensualite_habiter_3p AS mensualite_habiter_3p,
      ( 
       6371 * acos( 
              cos(radians(45.8219562)) 
              * cos(radians(lat)) 
              * cos(radians(lng) - radians(4.9013965)) 
              + sin(radians(45.8219562)) 
              * sin(radians(lat)) 
                  ) 
       ) AS distance 

FROM search_index asi 

WHERE 
     (mensualite_habiter_3p < 875.56) 
     AND (mensualite_habiter_3p > 619.5) 
     ORDER BY distance ASC, mensualite_habiter_3p ASC
```

The result I have :

[image]

How do I get only ONE result by 'nid_programme' ? In fact, the goal searched is to have this result :

```
 nid_lot    nid_programme   mensualite_habiter_3p   distance    
 1858       1805            676.41                  0.00013425878593145295
 1846       1804            683.44                  10.090534238610191
 1887       1808            794.4                   14.146197138015372
 1816       1792            700.7                   36.64897301190563
 1912       1811            774.58                  97.35583327362087
 1875       1807            870.43                  100.34682452197465
```

As you can see there is only one iteration of 'nid_programme' (the first one)

Comment: You can get one record as you expect but not exact you expect. You have to pick data either max or min of nid_lot, Is it acceptable ?

Comment: `As you can see there is only one iteration of 'nid_programme' (the first one) ` In other words, the one with the lowest mensualite_habiter_3p??

Comment: Yes the lowest mensualite_habiter_3p

Comment: If we get two lowest exactly same then ? I think it would better to do with nid_lot but it's obvious requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try `group by`

```
SELECT
    asi.nid_lot                    AS nid_lot,
    asi.nid_programme              AS nid_programme,
    MIN(asi.mensualite_habiter_3p) AS mensualite_habiter_3p,
    ( 6371 * acos( cos(radians(45.8219562)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians
    (4.9013965)) + sin(radians(45.8219562)) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance
FROM
    nh_actweb_search_index asi
WHERE
    (
        mensualite_habiter_3p < 875.56)
AND (
        mensualite_habiter_3p > 619.5)
GROUP BY
    asi.nid_programme
ORDER BY
    distance ASC,
    mensualite_habiter_3p ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if you want to get only one row for each nid_programme and I think nid_lot is holding unique data, so based on max or min nid_id you can pic that row but as you said based on lowest mensualite_habiter_3p, you can try the following.

---Based on Minimum value of mensualite_habiter_3p

```
SELECT 
    a.nid_lot, 
    a.nid_programme, 
    a.mensualite_habiter_3p, 
    a.distance
FROM tmptest a  
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.nid_programme, MIN(b.mensualite_habiter_3p) tot 
             FROM tmptest b 
            GROUP BY b.nid_programme) t ON t.tot = a.mensualite_habiter_3p
AND a.nid_programme = t.nid_programme
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted as desired result it looks like you want to group by [nid_programme] and use min for the rest of the columns:

```
SELECT 
       MIN(asi.nid_lot) AS nid_lot,
       asi.nid_programme AS nid_programme,
       MIN(asi.mensualite_habiter_3p) AS mensualite_habiter_3p,
      MIN(( 
       6371 * acos( 
              cos(radians(45.8219562)) 
              * cos(radians(lat)) 
              * cos(radians(lng) - radians(4.9013965)) 
              + sin(radians(45.8219562)) 
              * sin(radians(lat)) 
                  ) 
       )) AS distance 

FROM search_index asi 
WHERE 
     (mensualite_habiter_3p < 875.56) 
     AND (mensualite_habiter_3p > 619.5) 
GROUP BY asi.nid_programme
ORDER BY MIN(( 
       6371 * acos( 
              cos(radians(45.8219562)) 
              * cos(radians(lat)) 
              * cos(radians(lng) - radians(4.9013965)) 
              + sin(radians(45.8219562)) 
              * sin(radians(lat)) 
                  ) 
       )) ASC, MIN(asi.mensualite_habiter_3p) ASC
```